# How do I kick off a background process with Express and Node without timing out?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express route that I want to kick off a job and then return a 202. Like this...

```
const HANDLE_REQUEST = (req, res, next)=>{
    LOGGER.log("verbose", "Calling the GET");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        START_JOB(1, req.query.server, req.query.start, req.query.end);
    });
    res.status(202).send("Job Started");
    next();
};
router.get("/", HANDLE_REQUEST);
```

This works and the 202 is sent right away.

The problem is it times out after ~5 mins...

```
2019-05-01T09:47:29.074-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] Error: read ECONNRESET
2019-05-01T09:47:29.074-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
```

I tried setting the socket timeout and keep-alive like this...

```
    this.server = spdy.createServer(spdyOpts, this.express);
    this.server.on("connection", (socket)=>{
        socket.setTimeout(this.timeout * 60 * 1000);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true, this.timeout * 60 * 1000);
        socket.once("timeout", function(){
            LOGGER.log("error",`Timed out`);
            process.nextTick(socket.destroy);
        });
    });
    this.server.listen(this.port, (err)=>{
        if (err){
            LOGGER.log("error", err);
            return process.exit(1);
        }
        return LOGGER.log("info", `Server is listening on ${this.port}`);
    });
```

But this doesn't seem to help. Is there a way that I can kick off a background process (worker?) in Express on connection?

Comment: Your client times out but you set a timeout on the server side?

Comment: what does START_JOB do?  what does it return?  And your setTimeout doesn't have a delay.  It should be setTimeout(fn, delay).  But I don't think that's what you are really after and it will wait for the timeout and THEN start the job.

Comment: Why do you `next()`?  Is there something else in the middleware chain?

Comment: @zero298 no I was just trying to get the socket to close

Comment: @tagyoureit "Optional. The number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. If omitted, the value 0 is used" I don't care if it actually delays I just don't want it keeping the socket open

Comment: @rveerd I don't think it is the client that is timing out because I get the 202 and my client is no longer waiting

Comment: You might want to take a look at Socket.IO.  It establishes a two way communication path that is left open.  You can send events when your Job starts and then again when it ends and you don't need to worry about keeping the HTTP reply open.

Comment: `HANDLE_REQUEST` is the last handler in the middleware/handler chain. It should probably only take `(res, req)` as arguments and not call `next()`.